# Emulated docking the form is sized down, upon removing from dock the form only stays full size when it has focus with a mouse down

Tags: c#-4.0

Calling module:

```
    private void Indicator_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sizer size = new Sizer();
        int x = this.Location.X;
        int y = this.Location.Y;
        int width = this.Width;
        int height = this.Height;
        var screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 130;
        if (x >= screenWidth)
        {
            size.checkmove(x, y, width, height, this);
        }
        else if (width == 158 )
        {
            width = 235;
            height = 223;
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);
        }
    }
```

Module to Dock and reduce size from Sizer class:

```
    public void checkmove(int movex, int movey,int width, int height, Form mover)
    {
        var moverheight = mover.Height;
        var screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 130;
        var screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        var finalx = screenWidth;
        if (movex > screenWidth)
        {
            mover.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(154, 45);
            mover.Location = new Point(finalx, screenHeight - 600);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a different way to accomplish what I wanted by the double_click event on the form and just moving it out on to the desktop it full size, but I am still curious why it resizes back and forth to full size and reduced size while moving and appearing to flicker and ending up reduced and only showing full size when the mouse button is clicked on form and held down. I'm thinking it has to do with the resizeend call anytime the form is moved. And thanks Joran for the edit.